# Customize data-prototype attribute in Symfony 2 forms

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

I am trying to follow the Symfony 2.7 docs to create [Embed a Collection of Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) using a [custom Collection Prototype](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#cookbook-form-custom-prototype).

**Problem is, that I am not able to create a custom collection prototype as described in the docs.**

As in the example there are two simple classes: 
A `Task` class that manages the description of the task and additionally any number of tags, represented by its own `Tag` class

```
class Task {
    protected $description;
    protected $tags;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->tags = new array();
    }

    // Getter & Setter for description + additional addTag & removeTag methods
    // ...

    // Tags getter
    public function getTags() {
        return $this->tags;
    }
}

class Tag {
    protected $name;
    // ... setName(...), getName()...
}
```

**These are the custom form types:**

```
class TaskType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder->add('description');
        $builder->add('tags', 'collection', array('type' => new TagType()));
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'task';
    }

    // ...
}


class TagType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder->add('name');
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'tag';
    }

    // ...
}
```

**Twig file to render the form**

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {# render the task's only field: description #}
    {{ form_row(form.description) }}

    {# render tags - use table instead of ul as in example #}
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <th>{{ 'task.tag.headline'|trans }}</th>    
            </thead>
            <tbody class="tags-container" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.tags.vars.prototype)|e('html_attr') }}">   
                {{ form_row(form.rules) }}          
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

This works fine and renders the `tags` list inside the table. **However, this code uses the default prototype, that (of course) does not create table rows for the different tags.**

I tried to add the code to use a **custom prototype** as [described in the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#cookbook-form-custom-prototype). How ever the docs does not say anything about where to add this code or how to use it:

**Twig code WITH custom prototype code**

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {# Custom Prototype Code from docs #}
    {% form_theme form _self %}

    {% block _tags_entry_widget %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ form_widget(form.name) }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endblock %} 


    {# render the task's only field: description #}
    {{ form_row(form.description) }}

    {# render tags - use table instead of ul as in example #}
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <th>{{ 'task.tag.headline'|trans }}</th>    
            </thead>
            <tbody class="tags-container" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.tags.vars.prototype)|e('html_attr') }}">   
                {{ form_row(form.rules) }}          
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Using the custom prototype code like this results in the error:

> Method "name" for object "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" does
>   not exist in "MyAppBundle:Task:task.html.twig"

This sounds reasonable, since `name` belongs to the `Tag` class and not to the `Task` class.

**Problem 1:** How to use/access the `Tag` form inside the template?**

I removed `<td>{{ form_widget(form.name) }}</td>` from the prototype template and replaced it with `<td>Test</td>` to see if the template is used. The result: The template is NOT used and has no effect.

**Problem 2:** What is the correct way to set/activate the prototype template?

I found other threads dealing with prototype question/problems. The answers propose different solutions using macros, external twig files, etc. **Since the Symfony docs seems to offer a solution within the same file without using hacks like macros, I would like to know implement this solution.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is working for me - I am sorry - it is Symfony 3, but you should be able to translate.

In the buildForm method of my PersonType class, I have a CollectionType of **emails**

```
             ->add( 'emails', CollectionType::class, [
                'label' => 'common.email',
                'entry_type' => AppEmailType::class,
                'by_reference' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'label' => false,
                'empty_data' => null,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'delete_empty' => true,
                'mapped' => false,
                'prototype_name' => '__email__'
                ] )
```

The template to render the PersonType includes the emails form like so

```
{% include 'common/emails.html.twig' with {'form': form.emails } %}
```

**common/emails.html.twig**

This template is the container for the collection

```
   <div class="emails">
        <span class="sub-form-legend">{{'common.email'|trans}}</span>
        {{form_row(form)}}
        {% if form.vars.allow_add %}
        <div class="add-one-more-row">{{ 'common.add_one_more'|trans}}</div>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
```

In **fields.html.twig**, I have an entry_row template specific to the form, which uses a common email template defined in the same file.

```
{% block _user_person_emails_entry_row %}
    {{ block('_emails_entry_row') }}
{% endblock %}

{% block _emails_entry_row %}
    {% spaceless %}
        <div class="form-row email">
            <span class="type-select">{{ form_widget(form.type) }}</span>
            <span class="input">{{ form_widget(form.email) }}</span>
            <span class="comment">{{ form_widget(form.comment) }}</span>
            <span class="remove-form-row" title="{{'common.remove'|trans}}" id="email-__email__"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></span>
        </div>
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

To find out the name, trace the names of your forms and prefix them with an underscore.  Use **{{dump(form)}}** to get the unique name.

The HTML will be placed in the *data-prototype* attribute.